# symfony2 event dispatcher lazy loading listener

Tags: php, symfony, events, dispatcher, lazy-initialization

I'm creating some of my own events using Symfony Event Dispatcher, which works fine.

I noticed however, that the listener I configured in symfony is not lazy loaded, it is always initialized.
It is rarely used however.

The config in my services.yml looks like:

```
my.handler:
    class: Acme\AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection\MyHandler
    arguments:
      - @my.dependency
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: my.event, method: handle }
```

Is there a way to configure this in such a way that @my.handler is only initialised when the event is fired?
Because now it is initialised (along with all its dependencies) when it is pushed in the Dispatcher.

There is documentation about a ContainerAwareEventDispatcher:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/container_aware_dispatcher.html
But this only explains how to use it directly in PHP, not how to configure it in a standard symfony2 project.

Comment: Actually services should be lazy loaded, but another point is, that ctor's have to be cheap. Just save your ctor parameters to the private attributes. Don't do any connection or checks, so it doesn't matter if it's lazy loaded or not.

Comment: yes, all services are lazy loaded, but so are their dependencies when they are used. The EventDispatcher is always used in Symfony, so all listeners are always loaded, including their dependencies. implementing a "connect late" strategy in every service requires a lot of custom code. Loading the services lazy in these cases gives a generic solution for a common problem, and even works for third party services.

Comment: Also, constructors should not be cheap, just demand what is required by the service. Services should be as small as possible though and where possible delegate some tasks to other services. If you make the service itself "cheap", the constructor will become "cheap" as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define it as a **Lazy Services** adding the relative tag (as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html) ) as example:

```
my.handler:
    class: Acme\AcmeBundle\DependencyInjection\MyHandler
    lazy: true
    arguments:
      - @my.dependency
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: my.event, method: handle }
```

Remember to install the **ProxyManager bridge** as described in the doc.

Hope this help

Comment: Works as documented in the linked documentation. The ProxyManagerBridge is already installed in full-stack-symfony, it is ocramius/proxy-manager you still need to add through composer.

Comment: Also, it might be better (or faster) to lazy-load the dependencies of the listener, instead of the listener itself. But I did not test that. When using subscribers (instead of listeners) you will have to do just that.